# Eclipselink cache - preserving same object accross transactions

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm working with Eclipselink as a JPA provider.
The following code is used to access entities from the database:

```
    em.merge(anEntity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    anEntity2 = em.find(targetClass, anEntity.getId());
```

Is there a way to guarantee that the object `anEntity == anEntity2` will hold, that is always the same object reference is returned? For example somehow setting Eclipselink cache to always return the same entity?

**UPDATE**
I've read the following:

> In JPA object identity is maintained within a transaction, and (normally) within the same EntityManager. The exception is in a Java EE managed EntityManager, object identity is only maintained inside of a transaction.

Source: [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching#Object_Identity)

My question is this: in a Java EE environment, across transactions, (by using the variables in the link) does `assert (employee1 == employee2);` hold?
If not, is it possible to somehow bypass this limitation?

Comment: I'm not sure of the question, as if you are using the same EntityManager context, it maintains a context of all managed entities for its lifetime - unless you are calling em.clear().  You are using em.merge, so maybe your anEntity instance isn't the managed instance from the first transaction?  If not use anEntity = em.merge(anEntity);

Comment: Added some clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link states, the only exception is within a Java EE managed entityManager, as the container must control the EM's lifecycle, and generally releases them when the transaction commits.  The proxy you have a handle too will then re-obtain an EntityManager underneath as needed, or if a new transaction starts.  You can obtain the EntityManager directly from the factory though to avoid this situation, which the container can inject for you as well.  This allows you to control its lifecycle directly.

In the code you have provided though it is unlikely that anEntity == anEntity2 would be true, as if you need to call em.merge on anEntity, it is not a managed instance.  You need to keep a handle on the managed instance for it to remain constant for the life of the EntityManager.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow overcome this?

Comment: that anEntity != anEntity2?  Yes, by using the managed instance.  You did not show how you initially read in anEntity, but if you use this entityManager, it will be a managed instance and anEntity ==anEntity2 with no need for the merge.